# How to find length of object in photo when object is at certain angle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, angle

I have a picture of a section of a rectangular prism taken at an angle so that it isn't facing parallel with the camera like below. The end of the prism is cut off by the photo, and I have a scale for the photo (Example : $1$ pixel/micrometer).

**My question:** Is it possible to find the width of the box from the picture and scale even though it is at an angle? There are no shadows or additional info in the picture.

[image]

Comment: What could "1 pixel / micrometer" mean? In any picture, a pixel could be a large part of a faraway object or a smaller part of a same-sized closer object. Who told you "1 pixel / micrometer" and what did they mean?

Comment: For your picture, how could you know if it's a tiny prism close to the camera, or a huge one very far away?